# Sublime Text "Unable to save"

Tags: sublimetext3

I didnt change any file paths and everything was working fine. I made one quick change saved it ok, did another change and I went to save it and got the following error. How can I solve this. It will save other files ok

```
Unable to save
D:\xampp\htdocs\websites\dev.liverpool\style\main.scss
Error:
MoveFileEx(D:\xampp\htdocs\websites\dev.liverpool\style\.sublae1.tmp, D:\xampp\htdocs\websites\dev.liverpoolzstylezmain.scss) failed, 
Access is denied.
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling your plugins to see if it's the editor causing the issue or a plugin you installed? I'm thinking it might be a plugin issue since I don't think ST, by default does any file moves.

Comment: I have this often using Sublime v3 beta. Works sometimes and then this error pops up again and again. Need to wait then can save a file again. Happens at random files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just solved the same issue on Sublime Text 3 beta, Stable Channel Build 3065 by doing the following under Windows 7:

1. Navigate to the Sublime Text 3 executable file, wherever you have it installed.
2. Right-click it and select properties.
3. Click on the tab marked "Security"
4. About half way down the tab, on the right hand side, under the list of group and user names is this little button:

[image]

Click it.

5. If your machine is setup the way I suspect it is (otherwise you probably would not be having this issue), you should be prompted for your administrator account credentials. Enter them.

[image]

6. Now, select the Users group in the list, then take a look in the box at the bottom labeled 'Permissions for Users'. Put a check mark in the 'Allow' column for the 'Write' item.
7. Click 'Apply'
8. Click 'OK'

You should be set. What this does is it essentially gives Sublime the ability to write files while running with regular user privileges, no administrator level access required. Upon taking a better look at your error, what is happening is Sublime Text is creating a temp file for editing, rather than editing to file itself, then attempting to overwrite the original file with the temp on save. The problem is that the program is not being run by a user with sufficient privileges to perform the overwrite, hence the failure with an 'Access denied' message.

Comment: Any suggestions for mac please?

Comment: Followed the instructions here, but permissions were al ready set to allow Write access (and read and all others).  Yet I am still getting the error message when trying to save a file.  Trying to modify a Netbeans conf file to be specific.

Answer (score 21):

seems it's because Windows or another program is blocking the file. Sublime text uses a temporal file instead of editing the file directly, and when you save the file uses a API command to move this edited file to the original, so this command has restrictions when one file is locked and Sublime shows this alert.

Maybe this setting {"atomic_save": false} will work for you.

Comment: it sounds logic... in my case, i exit an app called Prepros, nothing change, but maybe the problem* is with a file sync app named 4sync (( by the way, really good ))

Comment: I am also using prepros. The best thing to do is not to "save as", but instead just create a new file and copy&paste the code into it.

Comment: This fixed it for me.  I'm using FTPUse to make an ftp folder look like a regular drive to all programs.  Notepad++, MS Word, Visual Studio, Brackets, everything worked fine except Sublime (3).  It would open the files fine, but not save them.  the atomic fix worked!!! Needs to be investigated.

Comment: Same thing here. Using SFTP Net Drive to map a remote server as a local Windows drive. When `atomic_save` is true, it gives me `Unable to save Q:\django_files\django_jquery_blog_post\public_files_for_aliteralmind\post_backup\post_3of3.txt: Error: MoveFileEx(Q:\django_files\django_jquery_blog_post\public_files_for_aliteralmind\post_backup\.subl649.tmp, Q:\django_files\django_jquery_blog_post\public_files_for_aliteralmind\post_backup\post_3of3.txt) failed, A device attached to the system is not functioning.`

Comment: For me, it was using SimpLESS.

Answer (score 13):

Go to the path where you installed sublime text 2 and...

1. Right click on the sublime_text 2.exe file.
2. Go to its properties.
3. Go to compatibility section under this.
4. Set its privilege level to "Run this program as an administrator".
5. Now change settings for all users and there also check the field "Run this program as an administrator".
6. Apply the changes.

Comment: Even though I had set sublime_text.exe in ProgramFiles to do this, I still had to go to the link in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and change the shortcut to also be run as an Administrator. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Problem persists for me.

Comment: As @Nathan Tuggy pointed out further down the comment chain, simply giving the program administrator privileges like that is not the wisest move. Any bugs or vulnerabilities in the program will then also have administrator level access to the machine it is running on.

Answer (score 4):

**A simple and effective solution:** **Right-click** on the file you want to save, in my case it is index.html, go to the properties and uncheck read-only. 
The Sublime text will start working fine. 
I have come across this error quite many times and by un-checking read-only file attribute of index.html, I am able to get rid of it

Comment: I have a similar issue as the original poster of the issue, and I tried doing this: from Properties, unchecking read-only. However, doing this does not take care of the issue. When I close out of the properties, I still keep getting this error, and when I go back to properties, the read-only box is checked again.

Answer (score 3):

I found out more ways to fix this:

- Close and reopen the Sublime Text windows or
- Open the file with Np++, add a space, save, quit, then you're prompted by ST to reload the file, click yes, and it works again... or
- Open the FTP console to see if there's a transaction in progress - then cancel it

In my case the SFTP plugin seems to be causing this problem, as when the FTP connection is timed out, the file which is waiting to be uploaded is being used, and you try to overwrite it.

Comment: I am also using Sublime SFTP and it seems this problem was caused by a hanging psftp.exe process. Once I killed it, ST started to behave again upon saving.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're using **ScoutApp** or **Compass**, they block your SCSS files because they are checking for changes as you specified for a directory for those files.

I suggest you reading this:

http://aspirecode.com/how-to-add-sass-support-in-sublime-text/

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

On mac using a remote volume sometimes I experience this. The solution is to remove the temp file then save again and all fixed.

IE: if you are working on test.html then the temp file would be ._test.html

Remove ._test.html then save again.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac-

Try changing the destination from 'Macintosh HD' to 'Documents' or any other folder.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin of `Superlime` solved this problem. It tries to save the file as root in SublimeText.

Reference Link: https://github.com/azubr/Superlime

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your SublimeText process priority to higher level in process manager (it has to have higher priority than your scss compiling app, if you're using one). 
It seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found this occurred when the folders are read-only. Right-click on the folders where your site is contained and see if read-only is selected in the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just open it as an administrator.

Because I want to edit anything and write as admin all the time, I set this program to always open as an administrator using "[Configure Applications to Always Run as an Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/ff431742(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)".

Comment: It is almost always best to avoid indiscriminately running as Administrator/root/sa etc. Otherwise, vulnerabilities can be exploited to greater effect.

Answer (score 0):

if it's not working after doing all suggestions, reinstall the program

Answer (score 0):

On Mac I saved the file in Home directory and it gave me this alert, later when I re saved the file again this time in Document directory the file is working now. Using SublimeText 3.

Answer (score -1):

Just got your file folder properties which you want to save and deselect to read only attribute.